# SimpleTestCursor robolectric 3.0-- compilation issue

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, robolectric, android-testing, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I am trying to test the cursor in my app.

But for the following import I get the error message-- cannot resolve symbol 
tester. I am using Robolectric 3.0. Why the import is not resolving, am I missing some dependency? I have looked internet but no support. Please help.

I am trying to use:[this API](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/2.4/org/robolectric/tester/android/database/SimpleTestCursor.html) and following is the import

```
import org.robolectric.tester.android.database.SimpleTestCursor;
```

These are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"

    testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that specific class?

Comment: @Eugen I have test cases with robolectric 2.4 , which I want to port to 3.0. But its tedious, provided no reference to depricated APIs

Comment: @EugenMartynov-- One more robolectric question, Please have a look:-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688359/robolectric-3-0-testing-vibrator-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleTestCursor has been replaced by RoboCursor in version 3 of Robolectric.

Have a look at robolectric/robolectric-shadows/shadows-core/src/main/java/org/robolectric/fakes/RoboCursor.java and robolectric/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/fakes/RoboCursorTest.java.

Comment: ThankYou Steve, that was what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you have any ides  to test Vibrator Service android. Please have a look on my question:-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688359/robolectric-3-0-testing-vibrator-service